# Specifying add and drop thresholds for stepwise regression in R

Tags: r, regression, stepwise-regression

I am running a stepwise regression using the F test as the criterion. Is there a way to explicitly set the add and drop thresholds (alpha levels) in R? The documentation does not make it clear.

Comment: For those who are forced to do stepwise regression for a homework problem (like I was when I asked the question originally), this is a relevant link: http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/02/stepwise-regression-in-r.html . Otherwise I agree with the responder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that this is not easy in R is a feature rather than a bug or deficiency representing advances in the science.

For example after the first step of a stepwise regression the t or f statistics computed conditional on that first step are no longer distributed according to the t or f distributions and therefore any specified alpha levels will be wrong.

Further, stepwise regression is known to give coefficient estimates that are biased away from 0 and tests on those coefficients that are generally meaningless.  Sometimes stepwise regression becomes essentially an inneficient method for selecting a random subset of predictors (rather than a meaningful one).  These days penalized methods such as lasso or ridge regression among others are preferred to stepwise methods.

Even better is to not do model selection if not needed.